# How many lines in Quran?

Tags: quran

I need to know number of lines for each Quran Surah, since I need them for calculating how many lines did a student study per a school term. I am using the popular Madani book for Quran print.

Is there any source for that?

Comment: This is correct, a page has 15 lines, but not always. Because some pages have less than 15, since they contain "surah headers" that decrease actual line number. Maybe I can use, but it is not 100% accurate.

Comment: You mean counting only pages that contain Surah Headers, right? This is easier at least than counting all pages. Thank you for your good idea. That way rest of pages * 15 will give me total lines. But the hard part is counting per surah, not the whole quran. I want to have a list of Surah and its lines.

Comment: Yes you should count pages with Surah headers possible footers or special stuff separately. But for the short Surahs you don't have any other possibility then to count the lines, but i think this is better then counting every page even if you could read meanwhile as a good deed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it will work if you do the math. There should be about 8,815 lines. In my mushaf there's 15 lines on every page including the name of the Surah and the bismillah that are on some pages. And there are 604 pages in this mushaf but the first two pages, surah fatihah and the first page of surah baqarah, are different so we won't count them. So 15 times 602 is 9,030. There are 114 Surahs so that means there are 227 lines that don't count because they are names of the Surahs and bismillahs (114 times times 2 = 228 minus 1 because surah tawbah has no bismillah = 227). So 9,030 - 227 = 8,803. Then add the lines of fatihah and the first page of baqarah which is 12 in my mushaf. 8,803 + 12 = 8,815. I have two full Arabic Qurans and this math applies to both of them.

Therefore, if I memorize 3 lines per day I should memorize the whole Quran in about 8 years. Because 8,815 lines divided by 3 =  2,938. Then 2,938 divided by 365 (days in a year) = 8.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the Madinan mushaf, but is the final page (ending with al-Nas) not a special page like the first two pages, or does al-Nas end neatly at the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 0):

With simple calculation:
**Includes Surah Names and Basmallah**
Page 1-2 = 8 x 2 = 16
Page 3-604 = 15lines/page x 602 = 9030
Total line (includes surah names and basmallah) = 16 + 9030 = 9046

**Exclude Surah Names and Basmallah**
Total line = 9046lines - (2lines/surah x 113surah) - (1line for At taubah)
Total line = 9046 - 226 - 1 = **8819 lines**

If you memorize **1 lines/day**, it will takes 8819 days = **24 years, 1 month, 22 days** to memorize the Qur'an.
If you memorize **3 lines/day**, it will takes 2940 days (roundup) = **8 years, 0 months, 18 days**.
If you memorize **5 lines/day**, it will takes 1764 days (roundup) = **4 years, 9 months, 29 days**.

Wallahu a'lam.

Comment: This similar with sister Yasmeen calculation, but she might reduce name+basmallah for Al Fatihah and Albaqarah twice.
4 lines from those two surah already reduced in (2x114) calculation, and when add the first two page of quran only add 12 page (already reduce 4 line).

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be 8820 because Al-Fatiha should only reduce one line (surah name only), not two, because the bismillah is an ayah. Therefore, we should treat Al-Fatiha like we do At-Tawbah by only reducing one line from each of these two surahs.

Comment: The basmalah is considered part of the surah regardless of whether it is before al-Fatiha or not, so why are you treating the basmala of al-Fatiha different to the basmala of any other surah?